# Tomcat server suddenly down on vps

Tags: vps, tomcat8, digital-ocean

I'm trying to hosting my project on **digital ocean vps**.

I used tomcat 8, jdk 1.8.

My environment setting is
[image]

Before I deploy my project, the tomcat server has no issue. Even when my project was deployed.

But when I access my project URL, i can't access and tomcat server can't access no more. I mean, tomcat home, manager-GUI etc.

Note. My Project has no issue in my local CentOS Server. Can run successfully.

My VPS setting is

Server - Digital Ocean

OS - CentOS 7

Processor - 1 Core

Memory - 512 MB

Storage - 20 GB ssd

Comment: I solve this issue by upgrading VPS Memory to 1 GB. It's OK.